# Laravel 5.5 url action

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces

I am calling `URL::action()` like this:

```
URL::action('\Acme\namespace\MyController@test');
```

and it works.

What I wanted to do is provide exact class instead of a string so that I have this:

```
URL::action(\Acme\namespace\MyController::class . '@test');
```

But this fails, and upon closer inspection, I noticed that

```
dump(\Acme\namespace\MyController::class)
```

doesn't return

```
\Acme\namespace\MyController::class
```

but

```
Acme\namespace\MyController::class <-- without leading slash
```

Which then doesn't catch the namespace right. Is there some special reason for that, and is there any workaround except doing:

```
URL::action('\\' . Acme\namespace\MyController::class . '@test')
```

**Additional**

If I use it without the namespace which is autoloaded in composer

```
"psr-4": {
    "App\\": "app/",
    "Acme\\": "acme/"
}
```

like this:

```
URL::action('namespace\MyController@test');
```

the `Acme\` is prepended automatically? How is this possible? I am calling this from my views which are not in `Acme` folder?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `URL::action('\\Acme\\namespace\\MyController@test');`?